# Can't open the dev menu in android emulator (RN 0.61.2 using CLI)

Tags: android, macos, react-native, android-emulator

I have a React Native 0.61.2 project(Using CLI not EXPO) and can't seem to open the dev menu on the android emulator.

I have tried `CMD + M` and `adb shell input keyevent 82` without a result. The app is running in dev mode `__DEV__.toString() results to true`. Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: Try to run `gradlew clean` inside android folder

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I ran `./gradlew clean` in the android folder the build was successful but the issue with the menu remains